# LINQ Group and Count with a Max

Tags: linq, count, max, linq-group

Can someone write a LINQ query for the following please

Given the data below I need the following
The Player with the highest score each week and the count of them if they win more than one week. If a tie results for the top score in a week then each player gets a count of one. The example data includes this situation

```
Week   Player         Points 
1      Steve            35 
1      Mark             29 
1      John             26 
2      John             23 
2      Mark             21 
2      Steve            21 
3      Mark             42 
3      John             42 
3      Steve            19 
4      Pete             28 
4      John             16 
4      Steve            14 
4      Mark             12
```

The result will be

```
Player         Count
Steve            1
John             2
Mark             1
Pete             1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would probably break this into two steps - which won't actually mean that anything gets executed any earlier, but it's simpler to understand.

```
// For each week, yield a sequence of winning results
var winningResultsByWeek = from result in results
                           group result by result.Week into week
                           let winningScore = week.Max(x => x.Points)
                           select week.Where(x => x.Points == winningScore)

var winsPerPlayer = from winningResults in winningResultsByWeek
                    from winningResult in winningResults
                    group winningResult by winningResult.Player into winsByPlayer
                    select new { Player = winsByPlayer.Key,
                                 Count = winsByPlayer.Count() };
```

The naming is very important here - hopefully by spelling things out I've made it reasonably clear. I'm sure there are other ways of doing it of course, but that's the clearest one I've thought of.

Comment: Excellent that does the trick. It seems such a simple problem but the detail is quite tricky. Thanks for the answer.